# Manually add /language/ to all Wordpress URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, multilingual

I am trying to turn a single language WP website into a multi language site, without using a plugin.

In practice I would like to manually add the language code to the page URL:
domain.com/company/ should become domain.com/en/company/

That should be applied to posts, pages, products and custom post types URLs.

So far I have tried some solutions, found here and elsewhere, without success.

Could anyone give me some hints, please?

Thank you, Paola

Comment: Why don't you want to use plugins? Without plugins, you won't have the same slug.

Comment: Hi @paolaG, it would be nice to know which solutions you tried and why they didn't work. Have you tried Wordpress Multisite?

Comment: @Maksym Kotov: I have a fulltime license for WPML and have used for many years by now, but I am trying to understand if I can find a much lighter solution, without plugin.

Comment: @clayRay: I have not tried WP multisite for the same reason above: simplify and remove burdens if possible. I could post some lines of code which I have used in my tests but they have been tested and deleted, therefore please allow me to get into the subject again in a couple of days, and I will do it. Thanks!